# Insert image background while using facet_wrap in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, facet-wrap, grob

I do not get to add a png background to my plot when using the facet_wrap option. Any idea what should work?

[my data is here](https://anonymshare.com/kbmQ/rmsep.csv)

```
library(grid) #complemantory for extra ggplot graphics
library(png) #Add a Background Image in ggplot
library(tidyverse) 

rmsep <- read.csv("rmsep.csv")
rmsep$RA <-  1-(rmsep$rmse/rmsep$sd.price)
```

plot without background:

```
rmsep %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(month), y = RA, colour = forecast_model)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  #scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(model_color, 0.6)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.4, 0.8)) +
  facet_wrap(~ rmsep$input, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Relative advantage") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))
```

[image]

plot with background:

```
rmsep %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(month), y = RA, colour = forecast_model)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(image = background, 
                                width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                                height = unit(1,"npc"))) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  #scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(model_color, 0.6)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.4, 0.8)) +
  facet_wrap(~ rmsep$input, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Relative advantage") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))
```

[image]

When combining them, I get the error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> :    replacement has 288 rows, data has 1

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to change `rmsep$input` to `input` in the faceting call. You need to facet by the data in the plot's layers, not the original data frame, which of course does not contain your image data.

I didn't have your `background` image, so I sourced another online:

```r
rmsep %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(month), y = RA, colour = forecast_model)) + 
  annotation_custom(rasterGrob(image = background, 
                                width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                                height = unit(1,"npc"))) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.4, 0.8)) +
  facet_wrap(.~input, ncol = 2) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Relative advantage") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0))
```

[image]